# Esconder la opción de copiar y pegar texto en android

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola,

Necesito quitar el cartelito que tengo señalado en la imagen, no quiero que aparezca al seleccionar el texto.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que deseas realizar es deshabilitar el menú con las opciones, puedes implementar y consumir la acción retornando un valor `true`:

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(
            new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [`setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(android.view.ActionMode.Callback)) para evitar lo que comentas. Si retornas `false` en `onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu)` hará que el "modo acción" no se ejecute (*Seleccionar todo*, *Copiar*, *Pegar* y *Cortar*).

```
tuTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Esto solo es válido si utilizas la API 11 o superior (Que supongo que usarás alguna superior)